# ng-bind && ng-bind-template

Tags: angularjs

Привет . 
В чем разница между директивами  ng-bind  и ng-bind-template ?

Написано что 
**Директива ng-bind-template позволяет задать шаблон привязки с использованием выражений.**

Покажите на примере разницу между директивами .

Answer (score 1):

В то время как `ng-bind` связывает занчение элемента с переменной, ng-bind-template позволяет использовать стандратный шаблонизатор:

```
<div ng-init="greeting = 'Hello World'; person.name = 'ganesan'; person.city ='delhi'">

    <h1 ng-bind-template = '{{ greeting }} {{ person.name }}, you are living in {{ person.city}}'></h1>
</div>
```